# Wild Cards File Rename Script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, for-loop, wildcard

I am trying to write a script which renames files based on a file extension.
The script should prompt the user for their desired file extension. Following that it should ask the user what prefix to prepend the file name(s). The default prefix should be today's date in the format of YYYY-DD-MM.

So if the user presses enter it should just use today's date as default. Otherwise it will use whatever the user has input for the prefix. After that I want it to display the original file name and the new name of the file on the same line, then finally the file should be renamed:

This is how i'd like the output to appear

**Example output 1:**

```
Please enter a file extension: gif
Please enter a file prefix: (Press ENTER for 201802­19). helpme
Renaming goose.gif to helpmegoose.gif.
```

**Example output 2:**

```
Please enter a file extension: gif
Please enter a file prefix: (Press ENTER for 2018­0219).
Renaming goose.gif to 2018­02­19goose.gif.
```

This is the code I have thus far:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /c/Users/johndoe/unix
curr=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")

echo -n "Please enter file extension: " ; read extension
echo -n "Please enter a file prefix(Press ENTER for ${curr}) " ; read prefix 

if [ -e $extension ]
then

for FILES in /c/Users/johndoe/unix/*.$extension
do
    echo -n "Renaming ${FILES} to " ; mv ${FILES} $prefix${FILES};
done
else 
    echo -n "Renaming ${FILES} to " ; mv ${FILES} $curr${FILES};
fi
```

Comment: You're testing for `$extension`, not `$prefix`!

Comment: `[ -e $extension ]` checks for a file called whatevers in $extension not the variable. I think you want `[[ -n $prefix ]]`

Comment: ah i see, what would you advise i modify that to?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd /c/Users/johndoe/unix || exit 1
curr=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")

IFS= read -rp "Enter file extension: " ext
IFS= read -rp "Enter prefix (ENTER for $curr): " prefix

shopt -s nullglob

for file in *".$ext"; do
    printf 'Renaming %s to %s.\n' "$file" "${prefix:-$curr}$file"
    mv -- "$file" "${prefix:-$curr}$file"
done
```